# error: ‘infinity’ does not name a type

Tags: c++

I have a program which contain many cpp files,I try to create a makefile but when I run it I got some errors related to this function:

```
void replace_infinites(cv::Mat_<int>& matrix) {
const unsigned int rows = matrix.rows,columns = matrix.cols;
//  assert( rows > 0 && columns > 0 );
if(rows==0 || columns==0)
    return;
double max = matrix(0, 0);
const auto infinity = std::numeric_limits<int>::infinity();

// Find the greatest value in the matrix that isn't infinity.
for ( unsigned int row = 0 ; row < rows ; row++ ) {
    for ( unsigned int col = 0 ; col < columns ; col++ ) {
        if ( matrix(row, col) != infinity ) {
            if ( max == infinity ) {
                max = matrix(row, col);
            } else {
                max = std::max<int>(max, matrix(row, col));
            }
        }
    }
}

// a value higher than the maximum value present in the matrix.
if ( max == infinity ) {
    // This case only occurs when all values are infinite.
    max = 0;
} else {
    max++;
}

for ( unsigned int row = 0 ; row < rows ; row++ ) {
    for ( unsigned int col = 0 ; col < columns ; col++ ) {
        if ( matrix(row, col) == infinity ) {
            matrix(row, col) = max;
        }
    }
}
```

}
I tried to include  :

```
#include <limits> 

using namespace std;
```

But when I compile my program I get these errors:

```
munkres.cpp: In function ‘void replace_infinites(cv::Mat_<int>&)’:
munkres.cpp:44:16: error: ‘infinity’ does not name a type
munkres.cpp:49:38: error: ‘infinity’ was not declared in this scope
munkres.cpp:60:17: error: ‘infinity’ was not declared in this scope
munkres.cpp:69:38: error: ‘infinity’ was not declared in this scope
```

I make a lot of research on the net but I didn't get any solution to fix my problem.

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<int>::infinity` is not useful anyways, integers have no inf. Use max instead.

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<int>::infinity()` returns `0` (according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/infinity)).

Comment: What is the actual line that the compiler complains about? Line 44 is not useful to us.

Comment: It would also be nice if you posted a [mcve] or at least told us which line in your example the error occurs in. Probably some `using namespace std;` related nonsense though, like the compiler picking up `std::max` where you try to use the variable `max` or what not. LPT: Forget about  `using namespace std;`, it does more harm than good.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: I changed it by std::numeric_limits<int>::max() and I got the same errors.I added -std=c++11 and same errors

Comment: @callyalater: line 44 refers to this:const auto infinity = std::numeric_limits<int>::infinity();

Comment: Then something is wrong with your installation, or your code differs from your description.   Assuming the `#include <limits>` occurs in the same source file, and BEFORE your offending code, I get no problems with gcc.   In short:  error cannot be reproduced.

Comment: That first comment of mine just pointed out an unrelated error, it was not supposed to be an answer. Anyways, the code you show looks fine, so please post an MCVE.

Comment: Can you show us more of your class code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems likely that you are not compiling with C++11 or higher, since your compiler is complaining about the following line:

```
const auto infinity = std::numeric_limits<int>::infinity();
```

Assuming you have indeed included [`#include <limits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/limits), there is nothing wrong with that line except the use of `auto`. Without C++11, the compiler doesn't know what `auto` is. Compile with C++11 or higher, or change `auto` to `int`.

Unrelated, and this was pointed out in the comments, but using [`numeric_limits<int>::infinity`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/infinity) is an awful, awful way of checking things. It doesn't make any sense to make an `int` comparison in regards to infinity. Prefer to use [`numeric_limits<int>::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max) instead (or whatever else suits your purposes).

Comment: Btw, *"using infinity is probably not a great way of checking things"* is somewhat of an understatement, it is flat out nonsense (when used with integers, for floating point numbers it's the way to go). May be worth to change that to avoid confusing beginners/people too lazy to read your links.